# How to edit an item from my Reducer Objec based only with the ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Reducer like this :

```js
clientData : {
1080 : [{ID : 1111,name : 'John'},{ID : 2222,name : 'Stan'},],
1090 : [{ID : 3333,name : 'Adam'},{ID : 4444,name : 'Alan'},]
}
```

And I want to be able to edit the 444 Id's element like this :

```js
{ID : 4444,name : 'New Value'}
```

So the output should look like :

```js
clientData : {
1080 : [{ID : 1111,name : 'John'},{ID : 2222,name : 'Stan'},],
1090 : [{ID : 3333,name : 'Adam'},{ID : 4444,name : 'New Value'},]
}
```

Have you an idea please how to achieve it ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it :

```js
const clientData = {
  1080 : [{ID : 1111,name : 'John'},{ID : 2222,name : 'Stan'},],
  1090 : [{ID : 3333,name : 'Adam'},{ID : 4444,name : 'Alan'},]
}
Object.values(clientData).forEach(ele => {
  let a = ele.find(el => el.ID === 4444)
  if (a) a.name = 'new value'
})
console.log(clientData)
```